# Replacement Pattern to get current node url

Tags: 7, views, entities

I'm looking for a **valid** replacement pattern, to get the url of the current node for a `custom text` in a `list` of filtered nodes.

Example markup for custom text field:

```
<a data-custom-attribute="john-doe" rel="123456789" href="[node:url]">[title]</a>
```

Unfortunately, Drupal doesn't show me any *useful* pattern examples:

[image: Screenshot of replacement patterns interface]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you want to do is add "Content: Path" as a field. This is the path to the node.

1. Make sure the "Exclude from display" box is checked.
2. After you have added the field, make sure it is above your custom text field (click the arrow next to "Add" and select "Rearrange").
3. Once, you've done that, [path] will become a replacement token.

Comment: Also of note, if you want an absolute path there's an option under *Rewrite results* to *Use absolute link*

Comment: In order to be able to use a properties of node-field of a node in the custom text for a view-field, the properties or node-field must be added as view-field before the customized one (exclude it from display to avoid displaying it twice).

Comment: @PierreBuyle, thats exactly what I said :)

Comment: @ScottJoudry Indeed, that's why it is a comment. I re-phrased it as a generic solution, while you explained the steps needed to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: Note: Make sure the Content: Path field is above the field you are trying to use to replace. Replacement tokens for each field are the fields above it in the view, not all the fields available.

Comment: This method didn't work for me as Path wasn't available. I used Link to Content instead as explained here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252011/output-this-field-as-a-custom-link-set-here-link-to-the-content

Comment: @cballenar, this answer is for D7, not D8+