# "Output this field as a custom link" set here link to the content

Tags: views, 8

How to set in "Output this field as a custom link" a link to the content.

In drupal 7 it looks like this:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1578524

Tried this, but this doesn't work:

[image]

Replacement patterns in `image` field:

[image]

And in `link to content` field:
[image]

Comment: Did you use the right token from the "Replacement Patterns" drop down in that interface?

Comment: where isn't suitable token in "Replacement Patterns" list

Comment: Did you add the node id field into the view?

Comment: Also, if you are "Link to the Content", you don't really need to supply the node path again.

Comment: I have the same issue. But I want to link to `event/{{ nid }}`

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

1. Add a `Link to Content` field, outer fields hide from display and remove links.

[image]

2. then setup `Link to Content` like this:

[image]

`Link to Content` haven't **link path** input - it always link to content.  This what I needed!